# how delegate can get the method address?

Tags: c#, delegates

I was wondering how delegate in c# can get the method address
method address can not be determined before runtime
then , how the delegate can figure out the method address at memory ? 
how it is working behind the scene

Comment: It's really up to the CLR - it doesn't necessarily have a direct address, it just has "a way to get at the method information" - and that's an implementation detail.

Comment: does that mean we can not get any information about that in detail ?

Comment: Well it means that it can vary based on the CLR. But basically you can pretty much ignore it - do you have a specific aim here, or are you just curious? I can't see how it would change the code you write.

Comment: This is a job for the CLR.  But can also be obtained in C# with MethodInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().

Comment: yes it dose not affect the code but I'm just wondering how does that work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do know exactly, but I think it works the same way as in the good old C.

At stage of compiling and linking every method has a fixed address relative to beginning of executable file. Addresses of everything you refered in your code are placed in a table at header of EXE. This table is called **Relocations**.

At stage of running OS loads the application to the free memory, *recalculates* all addresses in the table of Relocations, and then modifies the image of EXE with new (absolute) addresses.

Actually, the algorithm of running is a little more complicated, details can be found in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).